# Ignite cache: Serializable vs Externalizable

Tags: ignite

Which is better among Serializable and Externalizable? 
I have experienced Externalizable is slower than Serializable.
Can somebody help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, by default Ignite will not be using `Serializable` but will be marshalling with `BinaryMarshaller`. And that may be faster than `Externalizable`. Consider not having `Externalizable` unless it is explicitly needed.

Comment: It is needed. Is there any way to make things faster with Externalizable?

Comment: @AshishBhosle you can also implement `Binarylizable`, I believe it's faster and takes precedence.

Comment: The object is not just limited to the Ignite, we need to push it to the Kafka also

Comment: How does that relate to my recommendation?

Comment: I have to use Externalizable, and I want optimization on that. If I had to use  BinaryMarshaller, why would I asked this question?

Comment: You can use JdkMarshaller if Serializable is faster than Externalizable for you.